# how to call current year to onclick function using php

Tags: php

In below code i need to update current year in the place of 2017 how to add current year to that place

i found `$curYear = date('Y');` to display the current year. But i don't know how to call the particular variable in that place

please anyone help me regarding this. I am new to php. Thanks in advance....

```
 <td  align="left" width="30%">
    <input type="text" name="ToDate" id="ToDate" size="18" readonly="readonly" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="setYears(1947, 2017); showCalender(this, 'ToDate');">
    <img src="../calendar/calender.png"></a>
    </td>
```

Comment: Do you mean change the hard coded `2017` to the current year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file you are using is a `.php` file, you can replace the date with a php [`echo`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

```
<td  align="left" width="30%">
<input type="text" name="ToDate" id="ToDate" size="18" readonly="readonly" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="setYears(1947, <?php echo date('Y'); ?>); showCalender(this, 'ToDate');">
<img src="../calendar/calender.png"></a>
</td>
```

This will render as your example to the client.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
  $year = date('Y'); // or you want static then $year = 2017; 
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="setYears(1947, <?php echo $year; ?>); showCalender(this, 'ToDate');">
```